# Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be integers. Prove that if $a^2 \mid b$ and $b^3 \mid c$, then $a^4b^5 \mid c^3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be integers. Prove that if $a^2 \mid b$ and $b^3 \mid c$, then $a^4b^5 \mid c^3$.

**My (attempted) proof:**

Suppose that $a^2 \mid b$ and $b^3 \mid c$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers.

Therefore, we have that $a^2 k_1 = b$ and $b^3 k_2 = c$ for some $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I'm unsure of how to proceed from here. If I cube $a^2 k_1 = b$ to get $a^6 k_1 = b^3$, and then substitute this into $b^3 \mid c$, then I get $a^6k_1k_2 = c$, which isn't useful. The same happens if I do the other substitution.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify how I should be proceeding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your notations: $a^2 k_1 = b$ and $b^3 k_2 = c$ for some $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then 
$$c^3=b^9k_2^3=b^4b^5k_2^3=a^8k_1^4b^5k_2^3$$

Comment: Hmm, but this isn't $a^4b^5 \mid c^3$?

Comment: @ThePointer It sure is, but $a^8$ is $a^4a^4$, right?

Comment: Hmm. $a^4$ is just an integer, so could we say that $c^3=b^9k_2^3=b^4b^5k_2^3=a^8k_1^4b^5k_2^3 = a^4 a^4 k_1^4 b^5 k_2^3 = a^4 k_1 k_2 b^5$? Which means that $a^4b^5 \mid c$?

Comment: You are correct up to one thing: it is bad practice to change notations in the middle of a computation. Perhaps use another letter, e.g. a capital $K$, when $k_1$ changes values.

Comment: @Ahh, ok, that makes sense. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

For some integers $k,l$, we have $a^2k =b, b^3l = c$.

Hence $c^3 = b^9l^3 = a^{18}k^9l^3 = (a^{10}k^5)a^8k^4l^3  = b^5a^4(a^4k^4l^3)$

Answer (score 1):

I keep your notations and write $a^2 k_1 = b$ and $b^3 k_2 = c$. Then we have 
$$c^3=b^9k_2^3=b^2b^7k_2^3=(a^4k_1^2)b^7k_2^3$$
by squaring the first equation and replacing $b^2$. This can be written as 
$$c^3=(a^4b^5)k_3$$
where $k_3=b^2k_1^2k_2^3$ is an integer. Hence, $a^4b^5 \mid c^3$.